How to fix a locale warning from Perl?
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
perl -e exit:
                                                                                                                                                                        perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_GB:pl",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "Default.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "es_ES.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "es_ES.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "pl_PL.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_GB.UTF-8").

I've tried to remove/purge locale, reinstall, locale-gen and also
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales, but nothing changed.
I have en_GB.UTF-8, pl_PL.UTF-8, es_ES.UTF-8 installed.
localectl list-locales returns:
C.UTF-8
en_GB.UTF-8
es_ES.UTF-8
pl_PL.UTF-8

locale returns:
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:pl
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=Default.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

And I have similar problem with Java 17, when I print
System.out.println("file.encoding: " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
System.out.println("def charset: " + Charset.defaultCharset() );

output is:
file.encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
def charset: US-ASCII

How to fix this ? my locale should be en_GB.UTF-8

The problem comes from
LC_MEASUREMENT=Default.UTF-8

You need to find where that’s set and correct it. It could be somewhere in /etc or in your shell startup scripts.

wow ! that was it. I set it in Formats System Settings to explicit language and everything works now.
